# Why's this object not working?

Tags: javascript, html, arguments

```
box = new Object();
box.height = 30;
box.length = 20;

box.both = function(box.height, box.length) {
    return box.height * box.length;
}

document.write(box.both(10, 20));
```

Well as the title says.

First off I'd created an object.
Made to properties, height and length.
Assigned a value to each.
Made a method BOTH
In function I'd put 2 arguments which are object properties.
Returned their product.
And finally called the function giving it numerical value..

Why's this not working :(

Answer (score 4):

The problem is:

```
box.both=function(box.height,box.length){
```

`box.height` and `box.length` are not valid names for function parameters.  This should be:

```
box.both=function(h, l) {
   return h * l;
}
```

However, it seems you might be looking to get the area of the *current* box instance.  In that case, you don't need any parameters:

```
box.both=function() {
   return this.height * this.length;
}

document.write(box.both());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want it this way:

```
box = new Object();
box.height = 30;
box.length = 20;

box.both = function(height,length){
    this.height = height;
    this.length = length;
    return height*length;
}

document.write(box.both(10,20));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
box = new Object();
box.height = 30;
box.length = 20;

box.both = function() {
    return box.height * box.length;
}
```